# Running manage.py dumpdata on apps with dots in their names

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to do moving some data from my development machine to a server using `dumpdata` but ran into a problem.
So, say I want to dump the data that belongs to the app `django.contrib.auth`.
`django.contrib.auth` is in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.
This happens when I run
`$ python manage.py dumpdata django.contrib.auth`

Error: Unknown application: django.contrib.auth

The strange thing is that I can do `manage.py testserver` (i.e. nothing is broken) or do
`$ python

>>> import django.contrib.auth`

So there is nothing wrong with the python path.
I can run `dumpdata` on apps that are located straight in my project's dir.
If I leave out the apps' names, `django.contrib.auth`'s tables are dumped as expected.

So, why can't I point out a specific app with dots in the name? I have tried to dump
other apps that are located in `site-packages` with the same result.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try instead:

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth
```

The `dumpdata` command doesn't require the (fully qualified) package name of the app, only the name.

Comment: This is unintuitive behavior, as I would have expected Django to use the fully qualified package name, but allow the short name if there were no conflicts. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: As of today django apps must have unique names, so there will be ni conflicts possible.

Comment: Ugh. This doesn't work for me. I have an 'orders' app, as well as a 'dashboard.orders' app. Simpy using 'orders' only outputs data from the one app. :(